# How to, efficiently, search through many sql dump files of really big size

Tags: backup, restore

We have an ads website that the uncompressed(plain .sql file) size of the database is about 30gb. Until now when a user was deleting his classified the classified was completely getting wiped out from the database.We were always taking a full backup of the database every day and thus we have hundreds of this 30gb sql files . Sometimes there are users that asks us to give them some info about a classified that was deleted like 2 months ago(they usually dont know the exact date) and we have to search thought this back up files in order to find it.Is there a tool designed specifically for this task? I dont mean just a text editor that can handle big files , I mean a tool that can actually load the full database and let us do queries on it(maybe just simplified queries that involve only one table) and maybe even let us search many of the backup files at the same time(and no, loading the database in a sql server is not an option too since we need to quickly search thought tens of this backups).

Comment: If you want to do queries, you have to import it. Otherwise use `grep`. Or just stop deleting things - you can even prepare a table of "deleted", change all inserts to replaces and reimport all your dumps in there (only the table(s) you need. Dumps are just not meant for this.

Answer (score 1):

[ApexSQL Restore will mount the backup as virtual Database, and you can query it using SSMS.](http://blog.apexsql.com/easily-reattach-previously-used-virtual-sql-databases/)

I also published a PowerShell script that will let you analyze your backups in a given folder. I wrote it for analyzing size but you could easily adjust this to include properties like the date taken and such to find which backup you need to mount. You can find the script and article around it [here](http://www.sqlshack.com/analyzing-sql-server-backups/).

I have not played with the Apex tool extensively but do not believe it will search all backups in a folder for you to find the one with the specific data you need. You would have to mount at most the full and then all the logs to get it to the date you need.

I have never seen one that does exactly what you are looking for, but the above should help I think.